# Jenkins version upgrade from 1.613 to latest one

Tags: jenkins, version, upgrade

I want to upgrade my Jenkins version from 1.613 to latest one i.e 2.80 , As my current Jenkins version is 2 years old,  I see My java version is 1.7 and I want to upgrade the java version as newer Jenkins version needs Java 1.8 , Is there anyway I can upgrade my Jenkins without any downtime and without a mess ..? I am afraid I cant roll back java Once I upgrade it to 1.8 and also I am afraid of all plugins. What necessary action I need to take ..? I see my Jenkins is in /var/lib

Please help me guys

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just keep a backup of your original war file and your entire JENKINS_HOME directory, your risk is minimal if something goes wrong.

Something like this should make it pretty easy:

Try it all on a backup server first, though this is optional:

Copy the jenkins war file and the JENKINS_HOME directory to a new machine, set the JENKINS_HOME variable to point to the place you copied JENKINS_HOME to, then start Jenkins. Make sure it all works like it should. You can even make a copy on the same machine but in a different directory if you start it up on another port.  Now you can try the upgrade steps on non-production instance.

The actual upgrade should be fairly painless. Shut down Jenkins, make a backup of everything, then start Jenkins using the new war file. Log in and test. If something doesn't work, remove the JENKINS_HOME and replace with your backup. Start back up with the original war file.